# file_put_contents just clears the text file

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chipperyman573</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/fav.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="change.php">
  Top: <input type="text" name="top" /><br>
  Bottom: <input type="text" name="bottom" /><br>
  Time (MS): <input type="text" name="time" /><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fi = "/var/www/rtf/webR/top.txt";
file_put_contents($fi, $cont);
$cont = $_POST["top"];
}
?>
```

When I go to the change page (chipperyman573.com/rtf/webR/change.php) and I fill in the forms, then click submit, the text file simply clears itself. Why?

I want to clear the current contents of the text file and replace them with what I entered.

Comment: Did you notice `$cont` will be undefined?

Comment: Well, try declaring $cont before you write it to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're putting to the file before you set `$cont`. It should be:

```
$cont = $_POST["top"];
file_put_contents($fi, $cont);
```

or simply:

```
file_put_contents($fi, $_POST["top"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$cont` needs to be defined first, before `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are declaring $cont after file_put_contents:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fi = "/var/www/rtf/webR/top.txt";
file_put_contents($fi, $cont);
$cont = $_POST["top"];
```

Should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fi = "/var/www/rtf/webR/top.txt";
$cont = $_POST["top"];
file_put_contents($fi, $cont);
```